# In Perl does the object/handle returned from DBI->connect go out of scope if passed between functions (by return or input param)?

Tags: perl, function, scope, dbi, prepare

I get this error

Can't call method "prepare" without a package or object reference at ... [in createSqlTable line starting with my $execute].

with code similar to the following (snippets):

```
use othermodule1;
use othermodule2;

my $dbh = othermodule1::connectToDatabase();

if ( defined $databaseHandler )
{
  print "\ndatabaseHandler is defined here after calling connectToDatabase\n";
}

othermodule2::setDatabaseHandler( $databaseHandler );

othermodule2::createSqlTable();
```

othermodule1:

```
my $databaseHandler = unset;

sub connectToDatabase
{
  $databaseHandler = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:db','db','pwd') or die "Could not    connect to database: ";
}
```

othermodule2:

```
my $dbhandler = unset;

sub setDatabaseHandler
{
  $dbhandler = @_;
}


sub createSqlTable()
{
  my $query = "CREATE TABLE atable ( a CHAR(30) NULL, b CHAR(30) NULL )"; # etc...

  my $execute = $dbhandler ->prepare($myquery) or die "Couldn't prepare statement: " . $dbhandler->errstr;
  $execute->execute or die "Couldn't execute statement: " . $dbhandler->errstr;
}
```

Comment: btw, it's a database *handle* (i.e. a way of identifying a database connection), not a *handler* (something that handles something).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  $dbhandler = @_;
```

Is the problem. You are assigning in a scalar context - so the value of `scalar(@_)` will be assigned to `$dbhandler` - in this case, 1, since you passed 1-element parameter list.

It should be: `($dbhandler) = @_;` to use the list context or as an alternate idiom,  `$dbhandler = shift;`

Contrast:

```
$ perl -e 'sub x { $x = @_ ; print "$x\n"} ; x(33);'
1
$ perl -e 'sub x { ($x) = @_ ; print "$x\n"} ; x(33);'
33
```

---

A second, unrelated problem, is that you misnamed your variable. You have `$dbh` in main script yet after assigning it you keep using `$databaseHandler` instead.

```
if ( defined $databaseHandler )  # BAD
if ( defined $dbh )              # GOOD
```

---

The above mistake (using `$databaseHandler` instead of `$dbh`) does not show up/matter if your modules are defined in the same file as your main script above it, because first module's `my $databaseHandler` declaration places that variable in scope of the rest of the file (main script included). But it will **STOP** working, if your module is in its own file (second example below)

```
$ cat /tmp/p1.pm
package p1;
my $v = undef;
sub x {
    $v = 3;
}
1;
$ cat /tmp/x1.pl
use p1;
my $c = p1::x();
my $v_print =  defined $v ? $v : "_UNDEF_";
print "v=$v_print\nc=$c\n";

$ perl -I /tmp /tmp/x1.pl
v=_UNDEF_
c=3

###############################################

$ cat /tmp/x2.pl
package p1;
my $v = undef;
sub x {
    $v = 3;
}
1; # END package p1
package main;
my $c = p1::x();
my $v_print =  defined $v ? $v : "_UNDEF_";
print "v=$v_print\nc=$c\n";

$ perl /tmp/x2.pl
v=3
c=3
```

Comment: +1 and Accepted answer: ($dbhandler) = @_; That was the root cause of my problem. Another question is: is it efficient to pass around the handler (i.e. is it an object) or would it be better to return it as a reference, i.e. new code would be sub connectToDatabase { $databaseHandler = DBI->connect('DBI:mysql:db','db','pwd') or die "Could not connect to database: "; return /$databaseHandler; } and then do: $dbref = connectToDatabase() and deref it by doing ${ dbref }  thoughts?

Comment: PS. that should be ${ $dbref } not ${ dbref }

Comment: @Rob - Just as in Java (but for different reasons) there's no "object" being passed around, ever. The value being passed around is **already** a reference to an object, by design of how objects are implemented in the language (in Perl's case, by underlying blessed reference, usually to a hash). So, TL;DR version is "no reason to do `\$databaseHandler;`".

Comment: @ROB - ... OK, I fibbed a bit in the last comment in the interests of simplicity - IIRC you can also bless a regular scalar instead of a reference (see inside-out objects), but it doesn't change the answer to your question. "Object" value being passed around is always a blessed scalar, whether a reference or not, and no need exists to take a further reference to it.

Comment: +1 x2 @DVK good to know about not needing the further reference. I will have to undo it all in the code I just wrote today, in that case. It all worked though! But that's fine. It'll make it more maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing lexical scope and global scope.  `my` declares a variable as lexical - it cannot be seen outside of its defining scope.  Without that, it is (package) global, but you will get a warning about it if you `use strict`.

so `my $databaseHandler` inside othermodule1 cannot be seen outside that module.  The value can be returned from the function, but that variable name is private to the module.

Comment: It might be one of the problems. `use strict`. `use warnings`.

Comment: @mob - I'm not very clear on whether the modules are defined inside the same file as `main` package or not. If they are in the same (my original reading) it's not a problem. If they are NOT, it is, though IMHO stemming from accidentally using the wrong variable name (see my updated answer) and not from intentionally wrong scoping

Comment: @mob I am use strict use warnings

Comment: the problem you point out was a typo on my part. I should be returning the handle in connectToDatabase. I've also asked whether it would be efficient or not to return the handle, or a reference to it, using return \$databaseHandler ( into $dbh - which I should really then call $dbhref ) and then deref using ${ $dbh } to get at the handle. Just wondered if I was introducing inefficiency if the handle is an object that I am passing around.

Comment: +1 @DVK that's not the root problem - you fixed that. Thankyou. But he is right that it is (another) problem, as I've said in my earlier comment I should be returning a value from connectToDatabase - actually this is a typo, my original code does not have this fault.

Comment: So @evil otto I've +1'd your answer because of that (  I should be returning a value from connectToDatabase  ). I did not use original code in this question because the naming includes company specifics.